# How to move blob from one container to another preserving version ids using .NET sdk

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I need to move a blob from one container to another within the same storage account. Versioning is enabled on the storage account so a blob can have versions. There might be bookmarks to the blob versions, so I want to move the blob preserving version Ids.

Moving blob as Copy/Delete operations is not working as expected as on copy new version Ids are generated

```
    var sourceContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("files");
    var targetContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("documents");
    
    var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlobClient(blobName);
    var targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlobClient(blobName);
    
    var sourceBlobVersions = sourceContainer.GetBlobs(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.Version)
        .Where(a => a.Name == blobName)
        .OrderBy(a => DateTime.Parse(a.VersionId))
        .ToList();
    
    foreach (var blobItem in sourceBlobVersions)
    {
        var url = sourceBlob.WithVersion(blobItem.VersionId).Uri;
        var operation = await targetBlob.StartCopyFromUriAsync(url);
        await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300), CancellationToken.None);
    }
    await sourceBlob.DeleteAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
```

Is there any way to move a blob preserving version ids ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to move a blob preserving version ids ?

Unfortunately no. Version id is a system assigned property (like etag or snapshot id) that is automatically assigned by Blob Storage service.

When you copy a blob, a new blob is created and the version id assigned to it would be the date/time when that blob was created.

Comment: Thank you for response. Marking as answer as I couldn't find any way that makes this possible.